# Brightness Function Keys (F5 & F6) not working in RHEL 7, HP laptop

Tags: rhel, graphics, backlight

**Problem:** Backlight function keys don't work in KDE, but brightness can be adjusted via "Display Brightness" GUI located in lower right power management icon.

**Specs:**

- OS: RHEL 7
- Window manager: KDE
- Graphics card: NVIDIA Quadro M1000M
- Laptop: HP ZBook Studio G3

**Solutions attempted and failed:**

- Appending each of the following to grub line: 
  acpi_backlight=vendor
  acpi_backlight=video
  acpi_backlight=native
  acpi_backlight=
  acpi_backlight=none
- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi="` does not make the function buttons work and also has a side effect of not allowing me to change the brightness from the GUI or with changing the value in `/sys/class/backlight/`. Major fail

Comment: Try some of the answers here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/285421/how-to-make-the-brightness-keys-work-on-an-hp-folio-13 They are for Ubuntu so you might need to tweak them a bit for RHEL

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I was never able to get the function keys to lower the screen brightness.

**Solution**:

- Get nux-desktop for centos 7 repo
- Install xbacklight (testing `xbacklight -10` and `xbacklight +10` to validate it was going to work after install).
- Disabled nux-desktop in yum
- Setup keyboard shortcuts to lower/increase screen brightness. For some reason the 'Fn' button is not recognized in GNOME when setting up custom shortcut keys, so I had to use Ctrl + F5 and Ctrl + F6.

IMHO, this solution sucks, but it works.

Comment: Fascinating... so it wasn't an issue with the kernel talking to the backlight via ACPI, but something between the keyboard and the kernel.